# Under which username will this URL show up?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, security, exchange

At the end of everything month, our IT department sends us a list of all the domains we've visited through our browser.

In my case, I have two domains: `SoftServices\JohnH` and `SoftServices\JohnBrowser`.

Let's say I log on to my PC with `SoftServices\JohnH`. Then I open `FireFox` browser with the option `Run as different user`, enter credentials of `SoftServices\JohnBrowser` and visit `stackoverflow.com`.

Will this link show up under `SoftServices\JohnH` or `SoftServices\JohnBrowser`?

Comment: That's depended on how your IT department compiles that list.

Comment: As @Seth says, either they check the urls directly, or refer to what ports a user uses. So both can work. If you need to know, test it. Visit a site as one user and see as which user it comes in your report.

Comment: @LPChip: "Ports"?

Comment: @grawity I meant port shinffers which grabs ports and urls and what not... But basically it is what you mentioned in your answer... :P

Answer (score 5):

Impossible to answer – it completely depends on how your IT team *obtains* those domains. There is no standard method for stalking domain users. (Additionally, [corporate IT is off-topic.](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)) A few possibilities:

- Corporate proxy server with authentication, configured in your browser's "Proxy" settings: If it uses NTLM or Kerberos for 'transparent' authentication, then it will see the username that the browser process is running on. So if you launch the browser via RunAs as "JohnBrowser", it will authenticate to the proxy as "JohnBrowser" as well.
- Scraping your web browser's history out of `\Users\*\AppData`: Will be associated with the same account as the browser process runs on. So if the browser's profile is stored in `\Users\JohnBrowser\AppData`, then IT will *probably* list it under "JohnBrowser" as well.
- Web browser extension that sends the logs elsewhere: Depends. It could record the username that the browser process is running on, *or* the username that owns the whole desktop session (Terminal Services station), or even both.
- Standalone Windows program that watches the web browser's address bar: Most likely will associate everything with the initial user who owns the whole desktop.
- OS-based network traffic monitor on your computer (antivirus, parental control, etc.): Could be either – depends on the product, but I think the initial user (desktop owner) is more likely.
- DNS server or central DPI firewall logs: No direct association to the username, only to the computer. Probably rely on correlation with domain controller logs, such as "we've seen someone log in as `JohnH` to the same computer today". In this case it could be either, because it also depends on which *specific* logs are used – all authentications or just the first one for the day (and whether the domain controller can even distinguish the two login types.)

Finally, the log processing tool could simply **automatically replace** known secondary accounts with their primary owner, so *even if* the URL was logged under "JohnBrowser", it could still be shown as "JohnH" in the final list. (That is, unless the IT team *doesn't* know that you own two accounts, which is a whole new issue.)

Comment: Some companies even use browsers, which hide a whole virtual machine, where even more possibilities will arise. However, nice collection.